# My app crashes when using intent to create OpenGL activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, opengl-es, android-imagebutton

My app crashes when I use an intent to open an activity which creates a GLSurfaceView but the code compiles fine and if you set the activity "OpenGLES20Activity" as the main activity in the manifest, bypassing the splash screen, the app works but when the splash screen is made into the main activity, the app crashes when I press the button.

This is the code for the button used to send the intent:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
}

public void start_game(){
    Intent starter = new Intent(this,OpenGLES20Activity.class);
    startActivity(starter);
}
}
```

This is part of the code from the xml file for the splash screen:

```
    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/play_button"
    ...
    android:onClick="start_game"
    android:scaleType="fitEnd"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/start_button"/>
```

This is the code in the activity receiving the intent:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class OpenGLES20Activity extends Activity {
private GLSurfaceView mGLView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mGLView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this);
    setContentView(mGLView);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void start_game(add View view here){
    Intent starter = new Intent(this,OpenGLES20Activity.class);
    startActivity(starter);
}
```

Or however you want to call the parameter, but you have to pass it

Comment: I guess you get another error,when passing the parameter? When you try to print something out at the the frst line of `start_game()` does it work with the parameter?

Comment: Without the parameter you get an IllegaleStateExecption, right?

Comment: Nope. It's only when the button is pressed that it crashes on my phone. It compiles without errors with or without the parameter.

Comment: It's only crashes when pressing the button because it's an exception at runtime. If you write  `public void start_game(){
    Intent starter = new Intent(this,OpenGLES20Activity.class);
    startActivity(starter); , 
}` logcat will print ' java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method start(View)'....so if you write `public void start_game(View view){
    Intent starter = new Intent(this,OpenGLES20Activity.class);
    startActivity(starter); i'm 99,999% sure yo don't get this error message, if that is not enough, there is another error...
}

Comment: In order that more experienced developers can help you, post the error messages

Comment: There are no error messages. On my phone, the app simply crashes and says "AnimationTest" has stopped.

Comment: Not on the phone, at android studio....the place where error messages get printed out

Comment: [That what you see HERE at the bottom](https://www.google.at/search?q=android+monitor+logcat&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwiZ4vmok4LVAhVJb1AKHa6hBe0Q_AUIBigB&biw=1920&bih=950#imgrc=l6g9Ww5_Dnir9M:)

Comment: I figured out the error. It turns out that the activity wasn't declared in the manifest.